# MDBootstrap Messenger Like grid

Tags: html, css, mdbootstrap

I want to create a messenger like grid layout using bootstrap 4

my html is like the following

```
`<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">here is a ul of list of contacts</div>
     <div class="col-md-9 ml-auto">msgs display here</div>
     <div class="col-md-9 fixed-bottom ml-auto">textarea here</div>
   </div> 
 </div>`
```

I want the `msgs display here div` to start from top of the page till it reaches the text area `div` problem is, it always has the same height like the first `.col-md-3`.

How do i make the height of the middle div `.col-md-9` independent of the left one? And ofcourse keeping it responsive.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I assume (because I cannot see your CSS) that you declared a height for the row div. This makes all the elements have the same height. Create an ID for each element and call them in your CSS, ex):

```
#msg-display-here {

  /* height goes here */

}
```

and your div in the html should have an ID as you have 2 classes that are the same:

```
<div id="msg-display-here" class="col-md-9 ml-auto">msgs display here</div>
```

Comment: Also please post your CSS

Comment: I have no css added except for the `mdboostrap library`

Comment: Also when i define a `height` as you answered it does work, except that now it is not responsive

Comment: You're probably making the height in pixels. Make it a percentage or rem if you have a reference pixel number. Also, how are you doing this w/o CSS

Comment: Will give that a shot. Upon reading your post i just inlined the height to test. There is no custom css as of yet

Comment: I gave height to both `.col-md-3` and `.col-md-9` and it worked. Thanks @DannyV i wonder why when giving the height the first time it did not work.